# How do I update a cell in a database using AJAX button click?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This code doesn't work! The console.log prints

> "You are not subscribed to newsleter"

I want to be able to click the button and then it says

> "You are subscribed to newsleter"

This is my HTML

```
<button onclick="subscribe()">Subscribe to newsletter</button>
```

This is my script

```
function subscribe(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/test.php',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This is my PHP

```
<?php
$myQUERY ="SELECT * FROM user";
$myQUERY .=" UPDATE user";
$myQUERY .=" SET Subscribed='1'";
$myQUERY .=" WHERE DisplayName='Henry'";

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['Subscribed'] == 1) {
    echo 'You are subscribed to newsleter';
}
else
{
    echo 'You are not subscribed to newsleter';
}
?>
```

In the Database, newsletter subscription is set to 1 when subscribed and 0 when not subscribed

Comment: You never run your query and it doesn't look like you even have a database connection. If you had error checking enabled you would be getting errors that you could work with.

Comment: drop `$myQUERY ="SELECT * FROM user";` you should be getting an error for this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php or whatever you're trying to do here. Select? Update? Plus, you're not even querying.

Comment: I think its something to do with the query at the top, as the console is printing You are not subscribed (which is the current setting) so AJAX is definitley finding the test.php page

Comment: Where are you running `$myQUERY`? `$result` kinda magically shows up

Comment: or drop `$myQUERY .=" UPDATE user";
$myQUERY .=" SET Subscribed='1'";` that's what I think.

Comment: you are not even running query .http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: i'm really new to PHP/AJAX so bear with me

Comment: theres no need to be rude Fred i'm struggling trying to learn and have come here to try and gain some constructive help.

Comment: You need to read tutorials here before just dropping code that you don't know about. Sorry, but Stack isn't a tutorial site.

Comment: There are so many things that are wrong here. Your update query is wrong, it should be `$myQUERY = " UPDATE user SET Subscribed='1' WHERE DisplayName='Henry'";`. Then EXECUTE your query. And finally use [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) function to check whether the row has been updated or not.

Comment: @user3589485 Before you do anything make sure that you're properly connected to database.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I am connected to the database as everything else on the site relies on the database and that is all working

Comment: Don't be discouraged. It's true Stack isn't a tutorial site, but that's no reason for folks to be mean ;)

Just ensure that you are actually executing your query, and follow @RajdeepPaul's advice and use `mysqli_affected_rows() > 0` to check and see if the update was actually made properly. Once you ensure that the query is running (if you have phpmyadmin or a similar tool, you can check the query log), if you're still having problems, update your question with your new code and results.

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee I followed RajdeepPaul's advice and got it working by using mysqli_affected_rows() > 0 !